# Multiple openvpn clients in different hosts

Tags: vpn, openvpn, route, tunneling

I'm trying to run multiple openvpn instances at the same time, all works fine running a single one, but I would like to have several instances, one of each connected to a different host and from there be able to use the interface that I want.

I'm trying it like this:

**France.ovpn**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote france.privateinternetaccess.com
lport 1190
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/piaauth.txt
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.rsa.2048.pem
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.rsa.2048.crt
disable-occ
lport 1189
rport 1198
```

|

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/France.ovpn --dev tun0

Fri Dec 16 16:59:32 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  2 2016
Fri Dec 16 16:59:32 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Fri Dec 16 16:59:32 2016 WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/piaauth.txt' is group or others accessible
Fri Dec 16 16:59:32 2016 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Fri Dec 16 16:59:32 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]108.61.122.121:1198
Fri Dec 16 16:59:32 2016 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Dec 16 16:59:32 2016 [113b1963081eb5270c22e4405fb71051] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]108.61.122.121:1198
Fri Dec 16 16:59:34 2016 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Dec 16 16:59:34 2016 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Dec 16 16:59:34 2016 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri Dec 16 16:59:34 2016 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.43.10.6 peer 10.43.10.5
Fri Dec 16 16:59:34 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

After this everything is working. But when I run the next ovpn instance I get some errors.

**Toronto**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ca-toronto.privateinternetaccess.com
resolv-retry infinite
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/piaauth.txt
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.rsa.2048.pem
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.rsa.2048.crt
disable-occ
lport 1192
rport 1198
```

|

```
sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Toronto.ovpn --dev tun1

Fri Dec 16 16:59:57 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  2 2016
Fri Dec 16 16:59:57 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Fri Dec 16 16:59:57 2016 WARNING: file '/etc/openvpn/piaauth.txt' is group or others accessible
Fri Dec 16 16:59:57 2016 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Fri Dec 16 16:59:57 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]172.98.67.16:1198
Fri Dec 16 16:59:57 2016 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Dec 16 16:59:58 2016 [484ec5eff7d70137ae07ee3ec5e62b80] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.98.67.16:1198
Fri Dec 16 17:00:00 2016 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Fri Dec 16 17:00:00 2016 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Dec 16 17:00:00 2016 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Fri Dec 16 17:00:00 2016 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.84.10.6 peer 10.84.10.5
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Fri Dec 16 17:00:00 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Fri Dec 16 17:00:00 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Fri Dec 16 17:00:00 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Here **ip link** and **ip addr**, both fails.

This is my route table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.43.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
10.43.10.1      10.43.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.43.10.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.84.10.1      10.84.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
10.84.10.5      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
108.61.122.121. 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
128.0.0.0       10.43.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
172.98.67.16    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
```

And this my ifconfig

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          inet addr:192.168.1.128  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::beae:c5ff:fe5a:7ec/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1146017 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:727717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1500194552 (1.5 GB)  TX bytes:117446235 (117.4 MB)
          Interrupt:40 

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.43.10.6  P-t-P:10.43.10.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1715 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:2312566 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:170653 (170.6 KB)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.84.10.6  P-t-P:10.84.10.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I think that I only need to configure some routes, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st VPN instance addes 2 routes pushed by the server using `push "redirect-gateway def1`. Option **def1** overrides the default gateway by using `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1`.

The 2nd VPN instance tries the same and fails to add those 2 routes, because they already exist. Only 1 default route is allowed.

You have at least 2 options:

1. Add directive `route-noexec` to the client config of VPN instance 2

> **--route-noexec**
>
> Don't add or remove routes automatically. Instead pass routes to --route-up script using environmental variables.

Now routes will be pulled, but not added to your system. You can do your own routing using a script. Example:

```
route-up add-routes.sh
```

2. Or add directive `route-noexec` to the client config of both VPN instances

Add route-up scripts and setup policy based routing.

Comment: Thanks @rda, that did the trick, now I'm trying to apply the proper routes. I've created a new question because I think that is not appropriate to ask for routing here. Here it is: http://serverfault.com/questions/821583/routes-for-two-openvpn-connections-different-hosts-in-the-same-client